# WooCommerce - Rounding total prices before placing order when using 4 decimals prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

So I am currently working on a website that sells cereals and spices in bulk.

The unit for 1 product is 1 gram. I set a minimum order amount of let's say 100 units (100 grams) for a product. But the price for 1 gram can be very low (sometimes $0.0045 , so not even half a cent for 1g).

I also set a minimum to place an order and the cart has to be at least $15 total.

Sometimes a cart's total will be an amount with 4 decimals like $20.5517 . I would like the sub-total and total prices shown in the cart to be rounded up to 2 decimals. But I need to keep the items prices with the 4 decimals because that's the only way I can stay competitive with my prices.¸

Basically I need the back-end to keep the 4 decimals prices and show the 4 decimals on the products too (thats how its already set up) but I want the total to be rounded up before the customer can pay via paypal.

Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a solution**. But you will have to make yourself all the necesary changes in woocommerce related templates.

So first if you don't know how to customize WooCommerce templates correctly, read this:
[Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Then now with the custom function below that will do the job on displayed formatted html prices (changing prices from 4 decimals to 2 decimals  and keeping html tags arround), you will be able to make the necessary changes on woocommerce related templates:

```
function wc_shrink_price( $price_html ){
    // Extract the price (without formatting html code)
    $price = floatval(preg_replace('/[^0-9\.,]+/', '', $price_html));

    // Round price with 2 decimals precision
    $shrink_price = round($price, 2); 

    // Replace old existing price in the original html structure and return the result
    return str_replace($price, $shrink_price, $price_html);
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works

---

**USAGE EXAMPLE:**

On woocommerce template **`cart/cart_totals.php`** at line **`33`** you have this Original code:
*(for subtotal displayed price)*

```
<td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
```

If you search for [**`wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html.html#188-196) function you will see that is using this **`WC_Cart`** method: [**`WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart_subtotal) … 
So you can replace it this way:

```
<td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
<?php 
    // Replacement function by a WC_Cart method
    $subtotal_html_price = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();

    // Here we use our custom function to get a formated html price with 2 decimals
    echo wc_shrink_price( $subtotal_html_price );
?>
</td>
```

**So know as you can see you will need to do something similar for all cart prices.** 
The cart and checkout templates are in **`cart`** and **`checkout`** subfolders…
It's your time to work a bit!

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helps me a lot! Will be trying this as soon as I get back home and I will let you know if this works for me. But it looks like this should be the right solution!

Comment: @FrédéricByarelle-Bréard I have think about since your first question and I don't see another simplier way… So this is going to give you some home work :)

Comment: Yes a bit of homework bu it will be some good experience and I already learned something new about how woocommerce works and now I will always be looking at the templates instead of looking for plugins :)

Comment: There is 2 main ways: The 1st one is the hooks (action and filters) … If you can't do it by using available hooks, then you can override templates (the 2nd way). As you will see even in the WC templates you have some available hooks to make customizations without changing those templates...

Comment: This did not work for me but then again I am too much of a noob to understand what I have to do next. I tried replacing other functions in the cart_totals and checkout templates by using the WC_Cart method like you did for the other one.... the site kept working and nothing was broken but I never was able to display only 2 decimals... But I can't believe there's no such options,there has to be a more simple way of doing this. I simply want the displayed totals in cart and checkout to have 2 decimals instead of 4. :(